# Firestore Swift: Adding multiple child maps by updating data

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've come across a scenario where I want something structured like this:
[image]

I tried to do set the data by doing

```
var mapValues: [String : Any] {
            return [ user_uuid! :
                        [
                            "name" : AuthViewModel().decodeUserInfo()?.displayName! as Any,
                            "checkInTime" : "",
                            "checkOutTime" : "",
                        ]
            ]
        }
            
db.collection("Collection")
     .document(eventID).updateData(["attendees" : mapValues])
```

However, the problem with this is that it does not "append" a new child to the map. Instead, I am overriding it. Is there a way to add a new "element" without wiping everything else?
I am looking for something that works similar to `FieldValue.arrayUnion`, but without changing my structure to an array.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `updateData` the database writes only the fields that you specify, but for those fields any existing value in the database is indeed replaced.

If you want to add an item to the array and all your items are unique, you can use the [`array-union` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#swift_11).

Note that it is never possible to **update** a value in an array item, so if you want to say update the `name` for an existing item, you will have to:

1. Read the array from the document.
2. Update the array in your application code.
3. Write the entire array field back to the database.